# Java webdriver: Element not visible exception

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm having the following problem. I have a dropdown that is hidden so when I make the Select and run the test i get the following error:

```
 org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=30.0.1599.101)
```

This is my select:

```
Select s = new Select(dropDown);
s.selectByVisibleText("CHARGEBACK");
```

Is there a walk around it to manipulate hidden elements?. I found the following code in one of the posts:

```
 JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

This is the html code:

```
 <div class="ui-helper-hidden">
<select id="formLevel:levels_input" name="formLevel:levels_input">
<option value="541fac58-5ea8-44ef-9664-e7e48b6c6a3c">Seleccione un Registro</option>
<option value="dafc799c-4d5e-4b02-a882-74cb6ad98902">SECURITY</option>
<option value="e5416086-2036-4cd0-b23e-865747aa3f53">CALL CENTER</option>
<option value="7ea4b4ea-4f06-4d27-9541-1b0cf3f2aa22">CHARGEBACK</option>
<option value="0f915120-7b8f-4a33-b063-5d20a834b655">PREVENÇÃO A FRAUDE</option>
<option value="a8ef13e8-f4a5-43b8-a668-b769f6988565">ANALISE DE CREDITO</option>
<option value="83b65a26-d4cd-43d3-b3fa-2f7894ca454a">SUPORTE A CONTA</option>
<option value="163d0db9-590c-47a7-a271-218b2d27d8d9">REGULARIZAÇÃO FINANCEIRA</option>
```

And it doesn't work in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you make a valid test case that makes it visible, e.g. `click this, then change the dropdown when the element is visible`  It's bad test logic to manipulate hidden elements as users will not do this.

Comment: Also, if the element is supposed to be visible, and its throwing this error, then I would check your selector.  You may be selecting the wrong element.

Comment: The selector is fine because i can find the element but I can't select the option. P.S added the html code.

Comment: @user2752065 did you try my answer?

Comment: @sircapsalot actually, users will do this.  jquery-ui uses hidden elements all the time.  It seems difficult to test this.  I don't want to use the visible jquery-ui element, because the graphic department may change that tomorrow.  The underlying element holding the value is the most stable way to test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `WebDriver` tries to simulate real users, it cannot interact with elements which are invisible/hidden. To solve your issue, I think you would need to click on `div` first which will make the drop down visible and select option from the dropdown. I would recommend such an approach as opposed to pure Javascript way since it would simulate a real user. Give following a shot,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
WebElement triggerDropDown = driver.findElement(By
                .className("ui-helper-hidden"));
triggerDropDown.click();
WebElement selectElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                  .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("formLevel:levels_input")));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByVisibleText("SECURITY");
```

**Edit** updated the class name of triggerDropDown

Comment: I agree with this answer.  You wouldn't need to use a FluentWait (ignoring exceptions) on this type of interaction (because the div click has a immediate expected result) and so the WebDriverWait is perfect in this context.

Answer (score 6):

Hi There can be so many reason for this. I also faced this issue number of times and solved using different ways.

1- Using WebdriverWait that is also know as explicit wait

2- Using unique xpath- using xpath ways.

3- Get the size of element then click or perform any action on first one.

I documented all solution here [How to Solve Element not visible Exception](http://learn-automation.com/solve-elementnotvisibleexception-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree to sircapsalot. You should hold application business logic and "do like an user". And use this hack for workarounds only.

Answer:

Try this way

`document.getElementById('formLevel:levels_input').options[3].selected = "true"`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but does the following work?

s.selectByValue("7ea4b4ea-4f06-4d27-9541-1b0cf3f2aa22");

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the reasons and issues raised by the earlier answers, I encountered another cause worth mentioning.  In my case, a JavaScript on the page had to run after clicking a link on the page in order for the elements that I wanted to access to become visible.  That's ok *as long as your driver has JavaScript enabled*.  In my case, I was running without JavaScript, so even though the link was "clicked" programmatically, the elements were not becoming visible.  I was using `HtmlUnitDriver` with the default settings.  Ultimately I switched to `ChromeDriver`. (You can enable JavaScript on `HtmlUnitDriver`, but that - for other reasons - was not enough for me in my case.)