# Selenium Webdriver - How to select option from not-typical dropdown list

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm beginner both in Selenium and Java so forgive me if answer is obvious

I'm creating automated test in Selenium. One of things It has to do, is to select option from "Sort by" list on http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_tile_filtering (http://screencast.com/t/rrNLm6bDCnb1)

I know how to select options from normal dropdown lists, using Select. And by normal I mean list with `< select id= ... option ... option >` structure. But this one I showed you, seems to work another way.

So, how can I select option from this "Sort by" list?

Comment: Meantime I found something that allows to use so called "scLocators" in Selenium IDE. And they seems to work quite well. 

https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/UsingSelenium.html

Now I'm trying to make them work in Selenium Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a tricky one.  One way to attempt this would be to click on the down arrow (id=isx_2Z) and then use sendKeys to send up and down arrows to move to the option you want and sendKeys a return to select it.

Answer (score 0):

The use of Select boxes without `Select` does indeed create some problems. In such cases we have to follow the following 2 steps

1. Click on the drop down box and wait for the drop down values to appear
2. Select the required drop down value by clicking on it.

Usually, the `drop down` and `drop down values` are located in different parts of DOM. We have to correctly identify it by checking the page source.

In the example website you have mentioned,

**drop down** is located at

```
<div role="presentation" id="isc_2W" $89="isc_SelectItem_5" $9a="$9d" class="selectItemText" style="width:123px;height:12px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;line-height:-moz-block-height;" tabindex="1614">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

**drop down values** are located at

```
<tr aria-selected="true" id="isc_PickListMenu_0_row_0" role="option" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="1">
    <td style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 144px; overflow: hidden;" class="pickListCellSelected" align="left" height="16">
        <div role="presentation" cellclipdiv="true" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;WIDTH:140px;">Animal</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr aria-selected="false" id="isc_PickListMenu_0_row_1" role="option" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="2">
    <td style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 144px; overflow: hidden;" class="pickListCellDark" align="left" height="16">
        <div role="presentation" cellclipdiv="true" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;WIDTH:140px;">Life Span</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can use the following code to perform the operation.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_tile_filtering");
driver.findElement(By.id("isc_2W")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.='Life Span']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code ic working fine. You can use this code.

```
  driver.get("http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_tile_filtering");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='isc_2Z']")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='isc_PickListMenu_0_row_1']/td/div")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

Use WebDriverWait and xpath lookups to activate the dropdown, find the combo entry, and select it.  (refer to test method implementation below).

> The following is how I tested this would work

**Using FireBug/FirePath to find XPaths in Mozilla**

If you don't have it already, install **Firefox** with an add-on called **FireBug**. After you have FireBug install another add-on called **FirePath**.

Firepath makes it very easy to find the xpath of most elements on a page.[image: Turn On Firebug in Mozilla]

After you enable it, the window will display.  Select the 'FirePath' tab and click on the 'element selector' icon in the FireBug toolbar.  While that is depressed, as you hover over elements on the page the xpath will change.

[image: Use FirePath to find XPath]

---

**Testing the Lookups**

Using FirePath, I see the following possible options for resolving the reference "Life Span" in this interface.

- > **CSS**: ".pickListCellSelectedOverDark>div"
  >   **XPath**:".//*[@id='isc_PickListMenu_0_row_1']/td/div"

I've made a utility class for helping me test lookups for simple behavior so I plugged these values in there:

```
package stackoverflow.proof.selenium;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

import org.junit.Assert;

/**
 * Parameterized test which can be used to validate lookups for a single well-defined desired interaction in a Selenium test.
 * 
 * @see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151925/eclipse-java-selenium-webdriver-unable-to-select-dropdown-item-elementnotvisi/33167573#33167573"
 * @see ""
 * 
 * @author http://stackoverflow.com/users/5407189/jeremiah
 */
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SeleniumLookupValidationUtilTest {
    /** Test URL where the element should be validated.*/
    private static final String TEST_URL = "http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_tile_filtering";
    /** Function which converts a String into a {@link By#id(String)} reference.*/
    private static final Function<String, By> AS_ID_LOOKUP = new Function<String, By>() {
        public By apply(String arg0) {
            return By.id(arg0);
        }
    };
    /** Function which converts a String into a {@link By#xpath(String)} reference.*/
    private static final Function<String, By> AS_XPATH_LOOKUP = new Function<String, By>() {
        public By apply(String arg0) {
            return By.xpath(arg0);
        }
    };
    /** Function which converts a String into a {@link By#cssSelector(String)} reference.*/
    private static final Function<String, By> AS_CSS_SELECTOR_LOOKUP = new Function<String, By>() {
        public By apply(String arg0) {
            return By.cssSelector(arg0);
        }
    };
    /** Function which converts a String into a {@link By#className(String)} reference.*/
    private static final Function<String, By> AS_CLASS_NAME_LOOKUP = new Function<String, By>() {
        public By apply(String arg0) {
            return By.className(arg0);
        }
    };
    /** Function which converts a String into a {@link By#linkText(String)} reference.*/
    private static final Function<String, By> AS_LINK_TEXT_LOOKUP = new Function<String, By>() {
        public By apply(String arg0) {
            return By.linkText(arg0);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Creates the data for running the test instance.
     * @return Collection of Object arrays.  Each array in the collection represents a different test execution.
     */
    @Parameters(name="{0}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> buildLookups() {
        String[] ids = new String[]{};
        String[] xpaths = new String[]{".//*[@id='isc_PickListMenu_0_row_1']/td/div"};
        String[] cssSelectors = new String[]{".pickListCellSelectedOverDark>div"};
        String[] classNames = new String[]{};
        String[] linkTexts = new String[]{};

        //I use the map so I can loop through the dataset later.
        Map<Function<String, By>, String[]> associations = Maps.newHashMap();
        associations.put(AS_ID_LOOKUP, ids);
        associations.put(AS_XPATH_LOOKUP,xpaths);
        associations.put(AS_CSS_SELECTOR_LOOKUP, cssSelectors);
        associations.put(AS_CLASS_NAME_LOOKUP, classNames);
        associations.put(AS_LINK_TEXT_LOOKUP, linkTexts);

        List<Object[]> parameters = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (Function<String, By> converter: associations.keySet()) {
            String[] lookupStrings = associations.get(converter);
            for (String lookup : lookupStrings) {
                By by = converter.apply(lookup);
                parameters.add(new Object[]{by});
            }
        }

        return parameters;
    }

    /** The By lookup to use for the current test validation.*/
    private final By target;
    /** WebDriver for testing.*/
    private WebDriver driver;

    /**
     * Test constructor.
     * @param lookup By to be used for this validation.
     */
    public SeleniumLookupValidationUtilTest(By lookup) {
        this.target = lookup;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the webdriver and establishes our validation state.
     */
    @Before
    public void initWebDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(TEST_URL);

    }

    /**
     * Performs the thing we actually want to know about.
     */
    @Test
    public void performValidation() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        //Wait for GWT to load
        WebElement dropDown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='isc_2W']"))); //Find the drop down
        //Click the dropdown to expand the options
        dropDown.click();
        //The element should now be availalbe to us, so try to resolve it.
        WebElement dropDownOption = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(target));
        //Validate that the lookup we got is the one we wanted.
        Assert.assertEquals("Expected 'Sort By' Dropdown option 'Life Span' not found by provided lookup.", "Life Span", dropDownOption.getText());
        //Click it to select that option in the interface.
        dropDownOption.click();
        //Verify the combo updated as expected.
        Assert.assertEquals("'Sort By' Dropdown option 'Life Span' is not selected", "Life Span", dropDown.getText());
    }

    /**
     * Closes all test browser windows and destroys the driver reference.
     */
    @After
    public void destroyWebDriver() {
        for (String window : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(window);
            driver.close();
        }
    }
}
```

From the Junit Output you can clearly see the cssSelector I thought I had was incorrect, but the xpath will give me the behavior I'm looking for.

[image: Junit Result]

---

**WebDriverWait vs Thread.sleep in Selenium**

Please note the Test method implementation:

```
  /**
     * Performs the thing we actually want to know about.
     */
    @Test
    public void performValidation() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        //Wait for GWT to load
        WebElement dropDown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//*[@id='isc_2W']"))); //Find the drop down
        //Click the dropdown to expand the options
        dropDown.click();
        //The element should now be availalbe to us, so try to resolve it.
        WebElement dropDownOption = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(target));
        //Validate that the lookup we got is the one we wanted.
        Assert.assertEquals("Expected 'Sort By' Dropdown option 'Life Span' not found by provided lookup.", "Life Span", dropDownOption.getText());
        //Click it to select that option in the interface.
        dropDownOption.click();
        //Verify the combo updated as expected.
        Assert.assertEquals("'Sort By' Dropdown option 'Life Span' is not selected", "Life Span", dropDown.getText());
    }
```

**Thread.sleep** is typically seen as bad practice for two primary reasons.  First, in Selenium tests you're already taking a long time to run the actions.  Using Thread.sleep forces you to always wait the configured amount of time, there's no early exit from that behavior by default.  The second reason is that even when the sleep does exit you can only assume the state of the system is what you want, but cannot guarantee it with the standard in-line implementation.

**WebDriverWait** is the preferred alternative in the Selenium API.  It will prevent your test from proceeding until the condition you're looking for is valid.  It comes with a nice pre-packaged set of options in the ExpectedConditions class, and also leverages the Google Guava API if you ever find the need to make your own customized conditions.

To account for the timing issue, WebDriverWait will exit on one of two conditions.  Either the wait has expired waiting for your condition, OR the condition now exists and the test can proceed. In the latter instance, it doesn't matter how long you configured the wait for.  As soon as the condition is true the wait releases and the test moves on.

Best of Luck!