# Selenium webdriver: Dropdown element selection throws Element not visible exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using Selenium and Java Webdriver and I'm new to Selenium.
I have a similar problem as in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637507/java-webdriver-element-not-visible-exception/41614328#41614328) and I tried several approaches. I just want to get the first element of this dropdown (which will get longer soon) and select it to test the input mask with junit.
Here is a snippet of the website:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="customer in settingsCtrl.customers" value="1" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="select_option_4" style="" selected="selected">
<div class="md-text ng-binding">FirstCustomer</div>
<div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div>
</md-option>
```

I tried following:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);

    WebElement customer = driver.findElement(By.id("select_option_4"));
    //customer.click();

    //wait.wait();

    List <WebElement> rows = customer.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
    System.out.println("row size: " + rows.size());
    // Debug text
    Iterator<WebElement> i  = rows.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        WebElement row = i.next();
        System.out.println("row text: " + row.getText() );

    }
    rows.get(0).click();
```

The error msg is as in the thread: ElementNotVisibleException

Any suggestions?

Comment: where is the error getting thrown?

Comment: the rows.get(0).click();

Answer (score 1):

I think after `rows.get(0).click()`, the dropdown will be closed, that's why you get the error.

If you want to get all texts from the dropdown, do it before the line of code I mentioned above

Comment: I removed the customer.click() that caused some error, but you are completly right :) still the getText() appears empty in my console... the row size is 1

Comment: For debugging, instead of printing text, maybe you can print outerHtml of each row to see what you get: `row.getAttribute("outerHTML")`

Comment: Also check `outerHTML` of `customer`

Comment: ahh good tip thanks :) seems to be at the correct position also for customer
<div class="md-text ng-binding">
                  FirstCustomer
                </div>

Comment: hmm.. if you get the correct html for `customer` (with 2 div:s inside?), I cannot think of why row size could be 1.

Comment: The code is quite simple and clear, try to debug carefully every line to make sure everything works as expected

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried instead to treat the dropdown as a Select webelement?

Select custDrop = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select_option_4")));

List  rows = custDrop.getAllSelectedOptions();

Then all the dropdown values are in the rows string array.

If you merely want to select the first option, regardless:

custDrop..selectByIndex(0);

You can also select by value or by visible text if you know ahead of time what they are.

Comment: Yes I tried that before, but I get an UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "md-option"

Comment: That's my bad, I didn't catch that in the original HTML code.  I have no other idea except perhaps to try using sendKeys to drop-down the listbox instead of click?  I'm not sure, but perhaps sending it a down-arrow, since your ultimate goal is just to always select the first available option.

Answer (score 1):

Use below function to verify if element is visible on page or not.

```
isDisplayed()
```