# How to make element visible in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to execute below code its giving me exception as:-**`org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible`**

```
 WebElement elem = newDriver.findElement(By.name("loginId"));
    elem.get(0).clear();
    elem.get(0).sendKeys("asd");
```

even though element is present.

For more details see the below image.

[image]

I am trying to access input box below account label but its giving me exception as element is not visible.

I already used **`Actions`** tag and **`JavascriptExecutor`**

Any suggestions.

Comment: You can try this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637507/java-webdriver-element-not-visible-exception

Comment: @Kapil123
 thank you for your suggestion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interested element is inside an iframe:

[image]

So, before, you have to switch to the iframe:

```
    WebElement iframe= driver.findElement(By.id("alibaba-login-box"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

If you want to go "out" the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

The entire code:

```
    WebElement iframe= driver.findElement(By.id("alibaba-login-box"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("fm-login-id"));
    elem.clear();
    elem.sendKeys("asd");

    //when you want to return to the defaultContent
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works.
I was struggling with the problem more 5 hours, once again thank you for your help.