# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible while trying to locate google search result

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Facing " org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible" though I am able to locate element through xpath in DoM structure.Tried with explicit and implicate waits, still the exception continues.

```
package google;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Trail {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\Automation\\Software\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        // Opening URL

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text' and @id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("pineapple");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //giving input and clicking on search

        WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"btnK\"]"));
       JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"btnK\"]")).click();

        // Trying to click the first link available

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/*[@id=\"rso\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/child::*")));
        element.click();

        /* WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/*[@id=\"rso\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/child::*")));
        element.click();*/

}
}
```

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637507/java-webdriver-element-not-visible-exception)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java webdriver: Element not visible exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637507/java-webdriver-element-not-visible-exception)

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the first link available from the *Google Search Results* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* along with *ExpectedConditions* clause set to *elementToBeClickable* and you can use the following code block :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
WebElement search_field = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
search_field.sendKeys("pineapple");
search_field.submit();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='g']//h3/a"))).click();
System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
driver.quit();
```

Console Output :

```
Page Title is : Pineapple: Health Benefits, Recipes, Health Risks
```